# on back pressed from browser erases all my variable value

Tags: android, android-intent, android-browser

I have button.Onclicking button it cals->choose Browser->on choosing Browser it loads my Url.
on coming back from browser,all my previous locally set variable value are cleared.Variables have have values that are initialized with them.
for ex:

i=0.

inside method i assign  i=10

call browser now //
i use this code to call browser

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(strUrl));

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose browser"));
```

it loads Url//

now on coming back to activity

Varialble (i) value becomes 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the lifecycle of an Activity a little better.  When you leave and return from an Activity state is not automatically persisted.

Android Lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

You should use onSavedInstanceState to restore your state when you return to your Activity.  This is the code example the (linked) docs give:

```
static final String STATE_SCORE = "playerScore";
static final String STATE_LEVEL = "playerLevel";
...

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: Booger: ya its a better way.Actually i have a class inside a tab with activity group.on back pressed from browser it comes to starting level activity.TabActivty->Act 1(dint call finish())->Activ 2(dint call finish())->browser.on back pressed from browser it goes to TabActivty.Kindly help me with this

Comment: BUt it works fine with 4.0.3.it works fine with 2.3.3 emulator but create such bug inreal device with os  2.3.5

Comment: This is (and always has been) the way to persist state in Android apps (so hasn't changed since the OS was introduced).  Maybe you should start a new question with the problem you are now encountering (I think this one was sufficiently answered).

Answer (score 1):

declare your variable as static

```
static int i = 0;
```

this will not reset i to zero. on back press

Comment: dirty hack. using onSaveState is cleaner

Comment: Qadir Hussain:Thanks for suggesting. I already declared all my variables as static and tried.but it opens the activity as if it is opening for the first time..

Comment: you have to make all variables to the default values when you are exiting you app.

Comment: BUt it works fine with 4.0.3.it works fine with 2.3.3 emulator but create such bug inreal device with os  2.3.5